# C - false value of integer var

Tags: c

The output in the following code is really mysterious.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void funktion(int x) {}

void test() {
    int foo;
    printf("test = %d\n", foo);
}

int main() {
    test();
    funktion(5);
    test();

    return 0;
}
```

Why will the foo-var initialised with the value of the parameter of funktion()? I don't understand why foo-var is initialised by the function-parameter. I know that I can fix it with a explicit initialisation - but I want to understand the mystery. Thanks!

Comment: Undefined behavior is to use an uninitialized variable.

Comment: It is Undefined Behavior to read a value from an uninitialized variable.  It can be anything.

Comment: In C it's not undefined behavior. But the value of uninitialized local variables (like `foo`) is *indeterminate*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Is *printing* indeterminate value defined (yeah, I have had this discussion bookmarked somewhere..)?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I *think* so, but I'm not 100% certain. I think it's only UB if the indeterminate value is a *trap value* (which for integers will be never).

Comment: So it's only a coincidence that the value of foo is the parameter of funktion()? I think foo use the free spacecell from the parameter and initialised with the content of this space cell?

Comment: @Waldi It's up to the compiler on how to implement it. In your case it might be this way, but it is not something you can rely on.

Comment: Yes, it is possible that the memory segment that was used for the argument to funktion happened to be reused by foo.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I hadn't considered that distinction.  Makes sense.

Comment: Thanks to all for your help!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The only type guaranteed *not* to have a trap representation is ` unsigned char`.  Any other type may, depending on the implementation.  On systems most people are likely to encounter (i.e. x86 Linux or Windows) there typically aren't any.  A signed integer could have a trap representation if, for example, it uses one's compliment representation and does not support negative 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added comments to your `main()` function that explains why is it so. By the way, you're in undefined behaviour land, and different platforms might yield different results.

```
int main() {
    // no return, no parameter, one local variable of type int.
    // This pushes an int on the stack, uninitialized (the local variable).
    test();
    // Stack pointer is back to where it was.

    // no return, one int parameter, no local variables.
    // This pushes an int with value=5 on the stack (the parameter).
    funktion(5);
    // Stack pointer is back to where it was.

    // no return, no parameter, one local variable of type int.
    // This pushes an int on the stack, uninitialized (the local variable). 
    // Previous value of that memory comes from funktion() call.
    test();
    // Stack pointer is back to where it was.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of the mystery!